# How to move the border when sorting in excel vba?

Tags: vba, excel, border

I am going to sort the data base on the first column, however the border line did not move base on the sorted data.

Is it possible to move it using vba code?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is something like an idea. It is not the whole solution, but you can start from it and build your own, by removing the magic numbers etc...

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub SortingBorders()

    Dim rngMyRng    As Range
    Dim rngCell     As Range

    Set rngMyRng = Range("A1:A20")
    Call RemoveAllBorders(rngMyRng)

    For Each rngCell In rngMyRng
        If rngCell <> rngCell.Offset(1, 0) Then
            Range(rngCell.Offset(1, 0), rngCell.Offset(1, 5)).Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = xlContinuous
        End If
    Next rngCell

End Sub

Public Sub RemoveAllBorders(rngMyRng As Range)

    With rngMyRng
        .Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
        .Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
        .Borders(xlEdgeLeft).LineStyle = xlNone
        .Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = xlNone
        .Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlNone
        .Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlNone
        .Borders(xlInsideVertical).LineStyle = xlNone
        .Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).LineStyle = xlNone
    End With

End Sub
```

This is what you get:
[image]

The solution goes around column 1 and puts a border only when the condition `rngCell <> rngCell.Offset(1, 0)` is true.

Comment: Thank you for the idea. It is not the solution but the idea is correct. It works fine. Thank you